# Can't locate numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Earlier today, I executed:

```
conda install spyder=4.1.3
```

Seemed to finish successfully.

Now, re-running a previous program including 
import numpy as np

I get the following error:

> ImportError: Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While importing we detected an older version of numpy in ['/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy']. One method of fixing this is to repeatedly uninstall numpy until none is found, then reinstall this version.

How do I uninstall? Or do I really need to uninstall?

On a macBook Pro, running Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: When you Google'd "uninstall numpy" and "Something is wrong with the numpy installation", what did you find?

Answer (score 1):

It most likely seems like that your `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable was not updated with the update of the `NumPy` library. This means that you must manually adjust the `PYTHONPATH` to include the location of the new `NumPy`. In this case the best solution will be to replace the old one. Or you can always add new one to the end of the environmental variable list, separated by a colon from the previous records.

If you are using Unix/Linux - add this to your ~/.bashrc:

`export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/your/other/path"`

Or you can display the content of the variable using echo `command`:

`echo $PYTHONPATH`

And then edit the specific values you need. Anyways, I have to warn you that using two versions of `NumPy` might cause unexpected errors in the future. Therefore, it is recommended to use only one.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing Anaconda following the upgrade to spyder 4.1.3 corrected the problem. 
All packages are now in /opt/anaconda3/pkg